# Get error while fetching user details from Twitter SDK after few logins

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I am doing following code for get user details from Twitter. But, after few hours, I get error and I cannot get user details at that moment. Next day. I am able to get those details and after few logins, again I get error:

```
TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
[client loadUserWithID:userID completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
    {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *dicUser = @{ kTWTRIdStr         : user.userID,
                                   kTWTRScreenName    : user.screenName,
                                   kTWTRNameParam     : user.name,
                                   kTWTRProfilePicURL : user.profileImageURL
                                   };

        completionBlock(dicUser, nil);
    }
}];
```

I am getting following error:

> Error: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=99 "Request failed:
>   forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error
>   : Unable to verify your credentials (code 99),
>   TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)}

Comment: show your error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated my question with adding error I get

Comment: see this https://twittercommunity.com/t/application-only-authentication-error-99-unable-to-verify-your-credentials/2486

Comment: I have reffered to it but not getting what I should do..